# Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL: http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

Tags: angularjs, wordpress, ionic-framework, wordpress-rest-api

im trying to fetch json data from my wordpress site using angular js promise inside ionic 
with the following code :

```
    import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {Headers, Http} from '@angular/http';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
let apiUrl = 'http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts';

/*
  Generated class for the NewsProvider provider.

  See https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection for more info on providers
  and Angular DI.
*/
@Injectable()
export class NewsProvider {

  constructor(public http: Http) {
    console.log('Hello NewsProvider Provider');
  }


    getPosts(){

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) =>{
            let headers = new Headers();
            this.http.post(apiUrl, {headers: headers}).
            subscribe(res =>{
                resolve(res.json());
            }, (err) =>{
                reject(err);
            });

        });

    }
}
```

now when calling this method i get the following error :

Uncaught (in promise): Response with status: 401 Unauthorized for URL: http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts

and heer what netwokr debugging says :
[image]

[image]

and accessing http://example.com/wp-json/wp/v2/posts directly  from the browser return the expected result.

Answer (score 0):

my issue come from             this.http.post(apiUrl, {headers: headers}).

i should use the get not the post 
             this.http.get(apiUrl, {headers: headers}).